# Finding all $c\in \mathbb{Z}_5$ for which $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle x^3+2x+c\rangle$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Finding all $c\in \mathbb{Z}_5$ for which $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle x^3+2x+c\rangle$ is a field.

I have worked out $0$ is not because it factors to $x(x^2+2)$.
I believe that $c=1,2,3,4$ are all fields because it is irreducible, but I am not confident in this answer.  Can anyone help?

Comment: How did you show they are irreducible?  And yes, irreducibility would imply that it is a field.

Comment: Try $(x+4)(x^2+x+3)$

Comment: and $(x+1)(x^2+4x+3)$

Comment: f(x) has a root in the field if f(a) = 0 for some a. And if it has a root then it is factorable (reducible). So if you want to take the brute force method just plug in each of f(0), f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4) (which are all the values in $\Bbb Z_5$) and see what values of C will give you 0. Then those are the values you *don't* want

Comment: @Blaris One can substitute the values x=1,2,3,4 in the polynomial and find that the values of c  for which 1,2,3,4 can be a root of the polynomial $x^3+2x+c$ and hence it is not irreducible.  For Example, $1^3+2.1+c=3+c$ so for c=2 1 is a root of $x^3+2x+c$. So for c=2 it is not irreducible.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\mathbb Z_5[x]$ is a PID, so all prime ideals are maximal, i.e. $\mathbb Z_5[x]/\langle x^3+2x+c\rangle$ is a field iff $x^3+2x+c$ is prime (and since PIDs are UFDs, it suffices to show that $x^3+2x+c$ is irreducible). Since $x^3+2x+c$ has degree $3$, if it is not irreduible it must factor into a linear and a quadratic polynomial, thus it has a root. So it suffices to determine for which $c$ it has a root in $\mathbb Z_5$. Since $\mathbb Z_5$ is so small, the easiest way is probably to plug in each element of $\mathbb Z_5$ and see for what $c$ they are roots. This gives us:
$$\begin{align}
x=0 &: c=0\\
x=1 &: 3+c=0\\
x=2 &: 2+c=0\\
x=3 &: 3+c=0\\
x=4 &: 2+c=0\\
\end{align}$$
thus $x^3+2x+c$ is irreducible for $c=1,4$.

Answer (score 3):

$\Bbb Z_5[x] / \langle x^3 + 2x + c \rangle$ is a field iff $f(x) = x^3 + 2x + c$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z_5$. This is because $\Bbb Z_5$ is a field, so $\Bbb Z_5[x]$ is a Euclidean domain. In particular, every prime ideal in $\Bbb Z_5[x]$ is maximal, and an ideal is prime iff it's irreducible.

Since $\operatorname{deg} f(x) = 3$, $f(x)$ is irreducible iff it doesn't have any roots in $\Bbb Z_5$.

For each $k \in \Bbb Z_5$, solve $f(k) = 0$ for $c$ and dismiss this value of $c$. The values that are left in the end give a field. (Hint: Your current answer is wrong.)